# How to get the slope and intercept of a least squares regression line in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I've been having trouble getting MATLAB to divulge the slope and intercept of a least-squares regression line, based on a 2-D scatterplot. This seems like it should be easier than it's turning out to be, but all the existing tools MATLAB provides for regression tend to assume that I'm doing something more complicated than I want to do. I should be able to get it from a facility like `lsline`, but the IDE is playing hard-to-get with the source code. Does anyone know a quick and dirty way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you only trying to estimate the regression visually, from the scatterplot? If not, you can use the `polyfit()` function to get your estimates. Or even better, simply write your own function. If you make a column of 1's, and then place your independent axis variables into adjacent columns, and call that matrix X, and you store your dependent variable in a column vector called Y, then just compute `beta = (X'*X)\(X'*Y)`. The first entry of `beta` gives the intercept, and the subsequent entries give the coefficients of your regression variables.

Comment: I've got the source data to work with -- the trouble I've run into with my usual sources is that they seem to assume I know the value of the vector b in the starting equation A*x = b. If I knew that it would be fairly straightforward to calculate the pseudoinverse of A and use it to obtain the least-squares parameter estimate. But until I know what b is (or Y, in your example) I'm not sure how I would do that.

Comment: `Y` is just the vector of the dependent variables (whatever you're putting on the y-axis of your scatter plot). If you have the source data, it should be implicit in that data what `Y` is. The part people usually forget is to augment the `A` matrix with a column of ones, which is what lets you compute the intercept term right along with the other coefficients.

Comment: You can use a simpler formulation to calculate `beta`: `beta = X\Y`. MATLAB will automatically solve this problem in least-square sense.