# How to run a regression in MatLab to find out slope and intercept?

Tags: matlab, regression

I am trying do a regression to find out the the slope and intercept of the Capital Asset Pricing Model (CAPM) equation:

```
ER = B*RM + A
```

`ER` and `RM` are two known row vectors with size (`100x1`)

I would like to simulate `B` (the slope) and `A` (the intercept). Both should be a scalar.

I have done it in Excel, but I get totally different output as in MATLAB.

In MATLAB, I tried different functions, but no results:

```
B = ER\RM % I get output only B but not A(intercept).
[slope,intercept] = postreg(ER',RM') % I get vector, not a scalar. 
[r,m,b] = regress(RM,ER) %I get vector, not a scalar.
```

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: See the [Simple linear regression](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/linear-regression.html#buva8q5) section of the matlab manual.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the slope and intercept of a least squares regression line in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131823/how-to-get-the-slope-and-intercept-of-a-least-squares-regression-line-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [Simple linear regression](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/linear-regression.html#buva8q5) section of MATLAB, you can calculate it as follows:

```
X = [ones(size(RM)) RM];
b = X\ER; % solves X*b = ER in least-square sense

A = b(1);
B = b(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Matlab has a function for that:

```
p = polyfit(RM,ER,1); %p(1) = B, p(2) = A in ER = B*RM + A
```